# My transaction is in review for over 24hrs on blockchain, I want to cancel it

Tags: blockchain, address, block, transaction-verification, verification

Please I want to cancel my in review transaction on blockchain. How will I go about it. Please help me,I need answers as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cancel a transaction. You can broadcast another transaction with a higher transaction fee (replace-by-fee) sending back to an address you own and hope that gets confirmed before the original transaction (miner is incentivized to mine this replacement transaction rather than the original one). Or alternatively you can ask the recipient to send the funds back to you after it has been confirmed. But once you have broadcast a transaction there is no way of cancelling it and instantly removing it from other people's mempools.

Comment: How will I broadcast another transaction by replace by fee because when I try initiating another transaction all I got is insufficient fund. And the receiver is a scam, I sent him another fund on another platform and he end up blocking me with payment hoping he will get this too since have already initiated the transaction

Comment: Right most wallets won't support this. You'd need to be able to construct a transaction manually I think rather than using existing wallet functionality. Even the wallets that support RBF will be for bumping a fee to the original destination rather than attempting to change the destination of the funds. https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/b8qf4c/what_wallets_today_support_fee_bumping_ie/

Comment: Apparently BlueWallet has RBF support implemented as "Bump Fee" and "Cancel Transaction" if you can import your keys into a BlueWallet. If these are all your funds at stake then you've got nothing to lose. But if these are only a percentage of your funds be careful not to lose the rest of your funds by botching an attempted RBF, cancel transaction. Rushing isn't a great idea normally when you don't know what you are doing and haven't researched.

Comment: I’m new to this and don’t really know what to do…. Can you help me with some video to guild me on what to do?? You can send the video link to my mail please @ susw219@gmail.com

Comment: I don't think there are any good videos for RBF. Is your wallet a blockchain.com wallet?